# Moving icon after the text

Tags: php

I have this function to add an icon before the heading. I want to show the icon after the heading. Tried a lot of things didn't work.

```
    public static function add_anchors($text)
    {

        // Search for headlines.
        $pattern = '#<h([1-6])(?: [^>]+)?>(.+?)</h\1>#is';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $headlines, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        $offset = 0;

        if ($headlines) {
            foreach ($headlines[2] as $match) {
                list($headline, $pos) = $match;

                if (strlen($headline)) {
                    $anchor = \sanitize_title($headline);
                    $icon = '<a href="#' . $anchor . '" aria-hidden="true" class="aal_anchor" id="' . $anchor . '"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="aal_svg" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9h1v1H4c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5S2.55 3 4 3h4c1.45 0 3 1.69 3 3.5 0 1.41-.91 2.72-2 3.25V8.59c.58-.45 1-1.27 1-2.09C10 5.22 8.98 4 8 4H4c-.98 0-2 1.22-2 2.5S3 9 4 9zm9-3h-1v1h1c1 0 2 1.22 2 2.5S13.98 12 13 12H9c-.98 0-2-1.22-2-2.5 0-.83.42-1.64 1-2.09V6.25c-1.09.53-2 1.84-2 3.25C6 11.31 7.55 13 9 13h4c1.45 0 3-1.69 3-3.5S14.5 6 13 6z"></path></svg></a>';

                    $text    = substr_replace($text, $icon, $offset + $pos, 0); // Insert after H tag.
                    $offset += strlen($icon);
                }
            }
        }

        return $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how you should create markup. Instead use css classes and the pseudo anchors `:before` and `:after` for such things. You code will get _much_ easier to read, thus to maintain. And you gain structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using debugging, i found this working:

```php
function add_anchors($text)
{

    // Search for headlines.
    $pattern = '#<h([1-6])(?: [^>]+)?>(.+?)</h\1>#is';
    $lh1s = 4; // length of '<h1>'
    $lh1e = 5; // length of '</h1>'
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $headlines, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    $offset = 0;

    if ($headlines) {
        foreach ($headlines[2] as $match) {
            list($headline, $pos) = $match;

            if (strlen($headline)) {
                //$anchor = \sanitize_title($headline); 
                // commented above because I am missing this function sanitize_title()
                $anchor = $headline;
                $icon = '<a href="#' . $anchor . '" aria-hidden="true" class="aal_anchor" id="' . $anchor . '"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="aal_svg" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9h1v1H4c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5S2.55 3 4 3h4c1.45 0 3 1.69 3 3.5 0 1.41-.91 2.72-2 3.25V8.59c.58-.45 1-1.27 1-2.09C10 5.22 8.98 4 8 4H4c-.98 0-2 1.22-2 2.5S3 9 4 9zm9-3h-1v1h1c1 0 2 1.22 2 2.5S13.98 12 13 12H9c-.98 0-2-1.22-2-2.5 0-.83.42-1.64 1-2.09V6.25c-1.09.53-2 1.84-2 3.25C6 11.31 7.55 13 9 13h4c1.45 0 3-1.69 3-3.5S14.5 6 13 6z"></path></svg></a>';

                $text    = substr_replace($text, $icon, $offset + $pos + strlen($text) - $lh1s -$lh1e, 0); // Insert after H tag.
                $offset += strlen($icon);
            }
        }
    }

    return $text;
}


$text = "<h1>test</h1>";
print add_anchors($text);
```

You was replacing the text (`<h1>test</h1>`) from pos (`4`). But with this change it is replaced from the position after the text `test`. This is done by adding the length of $text, and subtracting the length of the start- and end- tag.